# getting a substring from a regular expression

Tags: regex, grep

Here is the line of text:

SRC='999'

where 999 can be any three digits.

I need a grep command that will return me the 999. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm trying this:

egrep "SRC=\'([0-9]+)\'"  /tmp/test/file

which returns:

SRC='112'

But I just want this:

112

Comment: I'm using QShell, running on an iSeries. The regular expression part I've figured out, it's the extracting just part of the line that I need that has me stymied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to do it using sed

```
grep SRC=\'.*\' | sed 's/SRC=.\(.*\)./\1/'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `-o` option on `grep` to return only the part of the string that matches the regex:

```
echo "SRC='999'" | grep -o -E '[0-9]{3}'
```

Comment: that is cool. Nice stuff to get versions of installed software
    ansible --version | grep -o -E "([0-9].*)*"

Answer (score 2):

Are the lines to match always in the format  `SRC='nnn'` ? Then you could use

```
grep SRC | cut -d"'" -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

just sed will do

```
$ echo SRC='999' | sed '/SRC/s/SRC=//'
999
```

Answer (score 0):

Platform grep or general regular expression?

Regex

```
SRC\=\'(\d{3})\'
```

Answer (score 0):

why grep? How about..

```
substr("SRC='999'",6,3)
```

Comment: This would be faster than running a regular expression, with the tradeoff that it would not handle any change in the format of the data (e.g. two digits instead of three).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with plain grep.  As the man page on my box states: "grep - print lines matching a pattern"  grep only prints lines, not part of lines.

I would recommend awk since it can do both the pattern matching and sub-line extracting:

```
awk -F\' ' /SRC/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score -1):

depends on your platform / language.

in Ruby:

```
string = "SRC = '999'"

string.match(/([0-9]{3})/).to_s.to_i
```

will return an integer